# Unable to add self signed certificate (.pfx file) to Local store

Tags: batch-file, ssl, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I am able to create .pfx file from my script but unable to add it to local store (under Certificates/Personal).
Although, I am able to double click on .pfx and install it manually.

But when using this script, it shows up in certmanager with Name X and under a different folder.

**Script (batch file):**

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.

echo %*

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64
makecert -sv SimulatorCertificate.pvk -n "CN=X" SimulatorCertificate.cer -r
pvk2pfx -pvk SimulatorCertificate.pvk -spc SimulatorCertificate.cer -pfx SimulatorCertificate.pfx -pi password

//THIS IS THE LINE RESPONSIBLE FOR ADDING IT TO STORE
CERTUTIL -f -p password -importpfx "SimulatorCertificate.pfx"

echo "done"

ECHO.
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT
```

**Command prompt says:**

[image]

**When I check in certmgr (here):**

[image]

There is no certificate added inside personal.  Instead, the new certificate gets added in other folder as shown, with name X.

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Should be asked on serverfault rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: I think the problem is because of CertUtil command, couldn't find enough on the MSDN documentation page though.

Comment: That doesn't change the nature of my comment.